# YCSB understanding the output

Tags: performance, testing, nosql, ycsb

I search in the site and found another question about that, but there's no answers.

I'm executing YCSB tool on a cassandra cluster, and the output of YCSB is:

```
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 302016.0 -> 05 mins 02 secs

[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 3311.0828565374018

[UPDATE], Operations, 499411

[UPDATE], AverageLatency(us), 2257.980987603397

[UPDATE], MinLatency(us), 389

[UPDATE], MaxLatency(us), 169380

[UPDATE], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 4

[UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 8

[UPDATE], Return=0, 499411

[UPDATE], 0, 50039

[UPDATE], 1, 222610

[UPDATE], 2, 138349

[UPDATE], 3, 49465
```

and it continue about 'till number 70. How does it mean? Are there the number of seconds in which are runs that number of operations? Strange, cause the test runs for over than 5 minutes as you can see from the voice overall.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The output indicates

- The total execution time was 05 mins 02 secs
- The average throughput was 3311.0828565374018 across all threads
- There were 499411 update operations
- The Average, Minimum, Maximum, 99th and 95th Percentile latency
- 499411 operations gave a return code of zero (All were successful. Non-zero return indicates failed operation)
- 50039 operations completed in less than 1ms.
- 222610 operations completed between 1 and 2ms.
- 138349 operations completed between 2 to 3ms.
- ...and so on...They will probably go up to 1000ms.

It is also possible to get a time-series for the latencies by adding the `-p timeseries.granularity=2000` switch to the ycsb command.

More information is available in [the documentation](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload#step-6-execute-the-workload)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I continue to not understand how is it possible that the most of operations are done in less than 10 ms while the entire test during 5 minutes! I mean, are the operations done in less than 10 ms executed by the client? Infact as you can see, the 99thPercentileLatency are 8.

I hope I was clear :P

Comment: The test by default runs in a single thread (unless you specified the `-threads` option). So the operations do not happen in parallel. Moreover, the client performs many boilerplate tasks that don't impact the benchmark and are therefore not counted in the calculations (e.g. Instantiating classes, doing the actual calculations do not impact latency). As for the percentile, I am not really sure how it is calculated.

Comment: Perfect, actually I use the -s otput to see the operations by 10 seconds. One last thing: I see that, always with ycsb tool, ycsb returns me a

`WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Failed all from region=usertable,user5151590341071383779,1384956970306.c298f9ff82ff593e6d9a1895445c966f., hostname=ip-10-253-27-32, port=60020
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Call to ip-10-253-27-32/10.253.27.32:60020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$CallTimeoutException: Call id=542, waitTime=65285, rpcTimetout=60000`

Why?

Comment: Sounds like the HBase client failed to connect, or timed out. I haven't used HBase. Perhaps you could post a new question with this one.